# I finished a Quantum Physics course. What is next?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, education

I have finished the [Quantum Mechanics: Beginner to Expert course](https://www.udemy.com/course/quantumphysics/) on Udemy. After finishing it, I felt like I'm an expert at QM and went to PSE to answer someone's question. It's pretty obvious what happened next. So what else should I learn so my knowledge/understanding of QM is complete?

Comment: Take problem books like Schaum's series and others. Solve as many problems as possible till you can solve them in sleep!!

Comment: *It's pretty obvious what happened next.* I don’t have enough reputation to see deleted answers. Do you know what flaw in your understanding was revealed by the reaction to your answer? Was it mathematical? Was it physical?  That might provide some useful background.

Comment: Congratulations on completing the course at 13!

Comment: Congrats on finishing that course. If you like video courses you could consider following MIT's Quantum Physics I, II, and/or III. Each video description on YouTube also has a link to exercises assigned at MIT for that course.

Here are links to the three courses: 
QP1: youtube.com/watch?v=jANZxzetPaQ&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60cspQn3N9dYRPiyVWDd80G&index=1

QP2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QI13S04w8dM&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60QlYNsy52fctVBOlk-4lYx&index=1

QP3: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OZXEb8FxZQ&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60Zcz8LnCDFI8RPqRhJbb4L&index=1

Comment: Some of that content will have been covered in the first course you took and some not, according to the description I see of the course you linked. You would have to outline the MIT content and choose which of it is new to you. I have watched a lot of Barton Zwiebach's MIT courses and he is a great teacher.

Comment: @Ghoster Thanks for the encouragement! :D

Comment: @doublefelix If you make this an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: I'd suggest concentrating on being 13 (if that's your age, you only get one try at that in your one life !) and make sure your grades in other subjects are high, because you'll typically need high grades across the board to go further into higher education regardless of what you believe you know now, or indeed regardless of how much you like or dislike particular subjects.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine My grades are fine. I finish my homework very quickly (and get good grades), so I use my spare time learning Math and occasionally Physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congrats on finishing that course. If you like video courses you could consider following MIT's Quantum Physics I, II, and/or III. I've watched hours of these and Barton Zwiebach is a great teacher. Each video description on YouTube also has a link to exercises assigned at MIT for that course. Here are links to the three courses:

QP1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jANZxzetPaQ&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60cspQn3N9dYRPiyVWDd80G&index=1

QP2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QI13S04w8dM&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60QlYNsy52fctVBOlk-4lYx&index=2

QP3: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OZXEb8FxZQ&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60Zcz8LnCDFI8RPqRhJbb4L&index=2

Some of that content will have been covered in the first course you took and some not, according to the description I see of the course you linked. You would have to outline the MIT content and choose which of it is new to you. The courses are real Quantum Mechanics courses at MIT.

I'd like to refer you to one more source if you want to understand quantum mechanics from its foundations up, which is Shankar's *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*. It is one of the most common graduate-level Quantum Mechanics textbooks. It is not too hard to find a PDF online. You could use it as a reference on the side with the MIT course. The most important chapters here are chapters 1 and 4.

- Shankar's chapter 1 covers the math behind Quantum Mechanics. He does so in a more sophisticated way than many other textbooks, which is beneficial to the reader, but in a less formal way than pure mathematicians would (which would be through a field called functional analysis). I would not recommend going more formal than this for physics - functional analysis has its merits but delving too deep into it can also distract from the physical content of the theory. Your time is most efficiently spent learning the physics directly. Chapter 1 is worth as much of your time as it needs. I spent months going back to it.
- Shankar's chapter 4 covers the postulates behind Quantum Mechanics. These are the core assumptions made in the theory, from which almost all results can be derived (there are some exceptions). This is great to master.

Shankar can read a bit dry at times. But it is clean and results in a great clarity of understanding.